# Make multiple HTTP request on BackButton clicked

Tags: android

`removeField` function make an async HTTP request. It's all okay except when I want to press the back button and want to make the requests.
How can I click on back button, then do all the requests and wait for their success responses, finally do the back action?

DetailsScreen.java

```
@Override
    public void backButtonTouched() {
        getActivity().onBackPressed();
        ((DetailsScreenPresenter) presenter).backButtonTouched();
    }
```

DetailsScreenPresenter.java

```
@Override
    public void backButtonTouched() {
        if (orderFields != null && orderFields.size() > 0) {
        for (OrderField orderField : orderFields) {
            removeField(order.getId(), orderField.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to wait for all the requests to complete before calling `getActivity().onBackPressed();`.

It seems you are using MVP, and if that is the case, I'd suggest waiting for the callbacks of the requests, inform the presenter and then the presenter can call something like `((DetailsScreen) view).getActivity().finish();`.

Also, I think it'd be important to show a loading while the process is going on and a flag to avoid starting the whole thing again. Something like:

DetailsScreen.java

```
@Override
    public void backButtonTouched() {
        ((DetailsScreenPresenter) presenter).backButtonTouched();
    }
```

DetailsScreenPresenter.java

```
@Override
    public void backButtonTouched() {
        if (finishing) return;
        finishing = true;
        view.showProgress();
        if (orderFields != null && orderFields.size() > 0) {
        for (OrderField orderField : orderFields) {
            removeField(order.getId(), orderField.getId());
        }
    }
}

// call something like this when the requests are done:
public void requestsCompleted() {
    ((DetailsScreen) view).getActivity().finish();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Almost perfect, the only issue I am facing now is how to getActivity() as I don't have the view object after the requestsCompleted.

Comment: It worked by sending the getActivity() as parameter and calling getActivity().onBackPressed(). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

do this by overRiding onBackPressed() method its a simple solution and works smooth

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     yourReuest{
         onSuccess(){
         super.onBackPressed();
         }

        onError(){
        Toast ERROR
        }
   }

}
```